# How can I make this sound better?

Tags: email, complaint

...The above are just some examples of many such occurrences - which are frequent - wherein I am put in situations where I have to pick up slack, I am stretched thin, clients don't get adequate care and ultimately imperilled."

Basically I want to say that what I had written was a few examples and that in actuality there are many such occurrences and that they are frequent. These occurrences are requiring me to always pick up slack and being stretched thin. These occurances are also endangering our clients because they are not getting enough attention.

Comment: This is out of scope for The Workplace. By the way, both "imperilled" and "endangering" are both really strong words.

Comment: If those clients are actually sick people in a hospital, I think it's a very good choice of words, if the clients are in danger of being 39% successful in their ad campaign instead of 41%, the words are not appropriate. Context matters.

Comment: This sounds like an English question. May be better answered on ELL stack exchange.

Comment: Break it up into multiple, short, declarative sentences. No passive voice. No subordinate clauses. Use bullet points. Don't exaggerate. Depending on the situation, downplaying it (for politeness) with softening adverbs etc may or may not be appropriate -- it would be understood that it is for politeness. However if audience is stubbornly ignoring it, maybe ok to be direct. Measure tone to trade that aspect of it off vs expectation if it provoking a defensive reaction.

Comment: @E.Aigle They usually consider this type of request off-topic (proofreading)

Comment: @juliana I'm pretty sure proofreading is off topic here too though

Comment: @E.Aigle That is abundantly clear, I'm just pointing out that migration to ELL or ELU will not be accepted there

Answer (score 3):

Does this need to be in an email? I would recommend a short thesis statement, and asking for a private meeting to discuss. For example, "I have some concerns in regards to priorities and my ability to complete all of my assigned tasks in a timely manner. I would like to ask your help, Can we meet and discuss?"

Answer (score 0):

In business writing, there is a tendency to want to sound educated (at least business educated).  This makes our sentences too long to express ideas cleanly, as many business efforts don't want their ideas expressed cleanly.

"We lost money last quarter." will drive fear in the hearts of every employee.  "The market contracted causing a temporary restriction in cash flow which when balanced across our divisions yields a realized negative growth opportunity positioning ourselves well for growth next quarter." says the same thing, but it takes a keen person to understand that.

In your case, you've become incomprehensible in this sentence, and you know it.  Shorten the sentence and use more, shorter sentences.  Also don't try to show off your intelligence by using college level words, your educational flourishes detract from the message.

> The examples above show that I am stretched thin.  I've been picking
> up the slack, but the problems remain.  I can't get my clients to act
> on these items.  I fear that their projects are exposed to more risk
> because of it.

I hesitate to write other's sentences; because, odds are I don't have their message correct in my head.  Please don't take this as a solution to your problem, read the reasoning behind it carefully and take it as a template to improve business writing.

Comment: Dan's comment is well taken.  You might find yourself regretting putting this in an email.  On the other hand, it might be a paper trail that is needed later.  Consider your options, as you can't take your written word back easily, you'll have to amend it if it strays.